# How to include a page in PHP if it’s in the root folder?

Tags: php, url, include, directory

So I have multiple PHP files organized in multiple folders and subfolders. I’we included the same PHP page into each page using `include('sidebar.php')`. My problem is that this *sidepar.php* contains link to pages from my site and if I click from a file from a subfolder the link is something like this: `posts/posts/post.php` instead of `posts/post.php`.

How could I fix this?

Oh and how it`s possible to include a file (include();) from the root folder to a files from different subfolders ?

Comment: You have to use absolute path, as Vincent [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422973/how-to-include-a-page-in-php-if-its-in-the-root-folder/4422989#4422989).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the link URLs from the root like this:

```
   <a href="/folder/folder/page.php">Link</a>
```

The leading slash is the key.

Comment: Another question: if I want to include a file from the root folder the same method should work ?

Comment: @coolboycsaba Yes. You can use the leading slash anywhere because it causes all URLs to be interpreted relative to the root.

Answer (score 0):

You could try appending a slash in front of the link.

For example:

```
<a href="/posts/post.php">Posts</a>
```

That way it will work in any page.

Answer (score 0):

This rather seems to be an issue with the URL references you are using within your documents.

Because you need to be aware that relative URLs are resolved from a base URL that is the current URL if not specified otherwise (see [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)). So a relative URL path like `posts/post.php` is resolved from the base URL path `/posts/post.php` it results in `/posts/posts/post.php`.

You can fix this by using absolute paths within your URL references like `/posts/post.php`.